# htaccess 301 redirect to index page

Tags: .htaccess

I need the sloution for home page 301  redirection.

If I enter http://www.starmed.dk/index.php in the browse bar, then it will be redirected to http://www.starmed.dk without index.php

Any idea how to do this with an HTACCESS 301 redirect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of apache are you using?

Comment: Apache Version- Apache, 
Apache API Version - 20051115

Answer (score 0):

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^starmed.dk[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.starmed.dk/$1 [r=301,nc]

//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 www.starmed.dk/index.php www.starmed.dk
```

Edit:

Perhaps your configuration is different. perhaps this:

```
RewriteRule ^www.starmed.dk/index.php$ www.starmed.dk/ [R=301]
```

Comment: I'm using HTTP_HOST instead of domain name (starmed.dk)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Please use HTTP_HOST & send me . If I'm using your above code, then I'm getting 500 Internal server error.

Comment: i had a quick google and everything also suggests writing it like it did. perhaps you have an older version of apache?

Comment: Its working fine by @starkeen code. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
DirectoryIndexRedirect Off
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R]
```